Create a new calculated column for a dataframe with multiple values per row of the original dataframe
Sometimes I want to calculate multiple values based on one column of each row of a dataframe.
In the tidyverse, dplyr now provides reframe as a counterpart to mutate for this, spitting out a longer dataframe, but it does not output the values of the other columns of the original dataframe so one loses the correspondence with the original dataframe.
How should the original dataframe be combined with the new dataframe?
As an example, say we want to produce a report of whether each character from Star Wars is light enough to box in the Olympics in various weight classes.
    boxingPopularWeightClasses <- c(57,80,92,9999) #kilograms
    boxingWeightClassName<-c("Featherweight","Middleweight","Heavyweight","Super Heavyweight")

    checkAllowedToCompeteInEachWeightClass <- function(mass) {
      mass < boxingPopularWeightClasses
    }

    library(dplyr)

    allowed <- starwars %>% rowwise() |>
      reframe( class = boxingWeightClassName,
               criterion = boxingPopularWeightClasses, 
               allowed = checkAllowedToCompeteInEachWeightClass(mass)
      ) 

head(allowed)

The above calculates eligibility (allowed) for each character, spitting out the following, where the other columns such as the character's name have been lost.
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  class             criterion allowed
  <chr>                 <dbl> <lgl>  
1 Featherweight            57 FALSE  
2 Middleweight             80 TRUE   
3 Heavyweight              92 TRUE   
4 Super Heavyweight      9999 TRUE   
5 Featherweight            57 FALSE  
6 Middleweight             80 TRUE  

How can we recombine this with the original dataframe?

I'm not sure I've totally understood, but do you just want a cross_join - cross_join(starwars, data.frame(boxingPopularWeightClasses, boxingWeightClassName)) ? That seems to give the same row count as your above allowed, but doesn't lose any info.

I think you just want a cross_join - which will join each row of dataset x to each of y, after which you can do your allowed calculation:
out <- cross_join(starwars, data.frame(boxingPopularWeightClasses, boxingWeightClassName)) %>%
    mutate(allowed = mass < boxingPopularWeightClasses)
head(out[c(1:3,15:17)])
## A tibble: 6 × 6
#  name         height  mass boxingPopularWeightC…¹ boxingWeightClassName allowed
#  <chr>         <int> <dbl>                  <dbl> <chr>                 <lgl>  
#1 Luke Skywal…    172    77                     57 Featherweight         FALSE  
#2 Luke Skywal…    172    77                     80 Middleweight          TRUE   
#3 Luke Skywal…    172    77                     92 Heavyweight           TRUE   
#4 Luke Skywal…    172    77                   9999 Super Heavyweight     TRUE   
#5 C-3PO           167    75                     57 Featherweight         FALSE  
#6 C-3PO           167    75                     80 Middleweight          TRUE   
## ℹ abbreviated name: ¹​boxingPopularWeightClasses


One can use slice and rep to replicate each row of the original to have the same number of rows as the new dataframe (number of weightclasses * number of characters):
#Duplicate original dataframe, each row repeat number of weightclasses times
longer_starwars<- starwars %>% slice(rep(1:n(), each = length(boxingWeightClassName)))

#Combine the new columns with the old (only the first 6 columns, for readability)
starwarsBoxingEligibility<- cbind(longer_starwars[,1:6], allowed)

head(starwarsBoxingEligibility

The above yields what I wanted (see below), although maybe there's a better way:
            name height mass hair_color skin_color eye_color             class criterion allowed
1 Luke Skywalker    172   77      blond       fair      blue     Featherweight        57   FALSE
2 Luke Skywalker    172   77      blond       fair      blue      Middleweight        80    TRUE
3 Luke Skywalker    172   77      blond       fair      blue       Heavyweight        92    TRUE
4 Luke Skywalker    172   77      blond       fair      blue Super Heavyweight      9999    TRUE
5          C-3PO    167   75       <NA>       gold    yellow     Featherweight        57   FALSE
6          C-3PO    167   75       <NA>       gold    yellow      Middleweight        80    TRUE


1) We can add the new columns while maintaining the pipeline by using group_modify and bind_cols with reframe.
Also to keep the example no larger than necessary we will cut down starwars to just the name and mass columns; however, the code still works unchanged even if we left in all columns.
This has the advantages of:

modularity. Defining the new columns in a single reframe, as in the question, providing a higher degree of modularity rather than dividing the columns into columns that are the same in each group (class, criterion) and varying columns (allowed) and dealing with them separately.
generality.  Because this handles all added columns at once it can handle cases where there are no added columns that are the same for each group (class, criterion) and where the number of rows to add varies by group without any additional complications.

Code--
library(dplyr)

starwars %>%
  select(name, mass) %>%  # optional
  group_by(name) %>%
  group_modify(~ bind_cols(.x, 
    reframe(.x,
      class = boxingWeightClassName,
      criterion = boxingPopularWeightClasses, 
      allowed = checkAllowedToCompeteInEachWeightClass(mass)
  ) ) ) %>%
  ungroup

giving
# A tibble: 348 × 5
   name              mass class             criterion allowed
   <chr>            <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl> <lgl>  
 1 Ackbar              83 Featherweight            57 FALSE  
 2 Ackbar              83 Middleweight             80 FALSE  
 3 Ackbar              83 Heavyweight              92 TRUE   
 4 Ackbar              83 Super Heavyweight      9999 TRUE   
 5 Adi Gallia          50 Featherweight            57 TRUE   
 6 Adi Gallia          50 Middleweight             80 TRUE   
 7 Adi Gallia          50 Heavyweight              92 TRUE   
 8 Adi Gallia          50 Super Heavyweight      9999 TRUE   
 9 Anakin Skywalker    84 Featherweight            57 FALSE  
10 Anakin Skywalker    84 Middleweight             80 FALSE  
# ℹ 338 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

2) We can create the new columns in a list column and then unnest it.  It has similar advantages to (1) and is shorter.  The output order differs for (1), which sorts by name, and (2).
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

starwars %>%
  select(name, mass) %>%  # optional
  mutate(data = list(reframe(cur_group(), 
      class = boxingWeightClassName,
      criterion = boxingPopularWeightClasses, 
      allowed = checkAllowedToCompeteInEachWeightClass(mass)
    )),
    .by = name) %>%
  unnest(data)

giving
# A tibble: 348 × 5
   name            mass class             criterion allowed
   <chr>          <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl> <lgl>  
 1 Luke Skywalker    77 Featherweight            57 FALSE  
 2 Luke Skywalker    77 Middleweight             80 TRUE   
 3 Luke Skywalker    77 Heavyweight              92 TRUE   
 4 Luke Skywalker    77 Super Heavyweight      9999 TRUE   
 5 C-3PO             75 Featherweight            57 FALSE  
 6 C-3PO             75 Middleweight             80 TRUE   
 7 C-3PO             75 Heavyweight              92 TRUE   
 8 C-3PO             75 Super Heavyweight      9999 TRUE   
 9 R2-D2             32 Featherweight            57 TRUE   
10 R2-D2             32 Middleweight             80 TRUE   
# ℹ 338 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

